# Heroku Slug size at 222 MB / Play Framework 2.1 /

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt, playframework-2.1

My app slug size on Heroku indicates 222 mb. Quite huge and beyond the 200MB allowed.

Thus, I've inspected these things:

- Inspect my source code size: **89,9 Mo** knowing that **80,2 Mo** comes from to play app's **target folder**.
- Check my .gitignore file to be sure that play app's target folder is well excluded. Here my .gitignore file:

> ```
> .DS_Store         
> logs   
> project/project    
> project/target   
> target                 // target well precised here
> tmp     
> .history    
> dist      
> /.idea     
> / *.iml  //space here otherwise appears as a comment here    
> /out     
> /.idea_modules    
> /.classpath    
> /.project    
> /RUNNING_PID     
> /.settings
> ```

Check my SBT ivy cache size: **100,9 Mo**

Here the size of each folder (on the left) in detail:

> MikaPc:cache Mika$ du -xak .|sort -n|tail -50
>   1664  ./org.neo4j/neo4j/docs
>   1664  ./org.neo4j/neo4j/docs/neo4j-1.9.M05-javadoc.jar
>   1668  ./org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel/docs
>   1668  ./org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel/docs/neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05-javadoc.jar
>   1680  ./org.springframework/spring-test     1748  ./org.neo4j/neo4j
>   1752  ./org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars
>   1752  ./org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.7.1.jar
>   1860  ./org.springframework/spring-jdbc
>   1888  ./org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons
>   1980  ./org.scala-sbt/main/jars
>   1980  ./org.scala-sbt/main/jars/main-0.12.2.jar
>   1992  ./org.scala-sbt/main
>   2100  ./org.springframework/spring-context/docs
>   2100  ./org.springframework/spring-context/docs/spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
>   2104  ./com.sun.jersey     2348   ./org.springframework/spring-core
>   2356  ./org.springframework.data/spring-data-neo4j
>   2404  ./org.springframework/spring-beans
>   2776  ./org.apache.lucene/lucene-core
>   2800  ./org.springframework/spring-web
>   2808  ./org.springframework/spring-webmvc
>   2812  ./org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/docs
>   2812  ./org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/docs/aspectjweaver-1.7.1-javadoc.jar 
>   2844  ./org.apache.lucene         3016    ./org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel/jars
>   3820  ./org.springframework/spring-context
>   4356  ./org.neo4j/neo4j-cypher/jars
>   4356  ./org.neo4j/neo4j-cypher/jars/neo4j-cypher-1.9.M05.jar
>   4436  ./org.specs2/specs2_2.10/docs
>   4436  ./org.specs2/specs2_2.10/docs/specs2_2.10-1.13.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
>   4584  ./org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.10/docs
>   4584  ./org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.10/docs/scalaz-core_2.10-7.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
>   4824  ./org.neo4j/neo4j-cypher          5712  ./org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel
>   5936  ./org.aspectj/aspectjweaver
>   6024  ./org.springframework.data       6484   ./org.aspectj
>   6520  ./org.specs2/specs2_2.10/jars
>   6520  ./org.specs2/specs2_2.10/jars/specs2_2.10-1.13.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   6812  ./org.scala-sbt         8288    ./org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.10/jars
>   8288  ./org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.10/jars/scalaz-core_2.10-7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   11500 ./org.specs2/specs2_2.10         11524  ./org.specs2
>   13132 ./org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.10           13140   ./org.scalaz
>   15832 ./org.neo4j          23500  ./org.springframework
>   98552 .

My SBT build file contains the following dependencies:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    "org.springframework" % "spring-aop" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-aspects" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-beans" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-commons-core" % "1.4.1.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-expression" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-jdbc" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-orm" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-test" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-tx" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j" % "2.2.0.RELEASE" excludeAll(
      ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jdmk"),
      ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jmx"),
      ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.jms")
      ),
    "org.neo4j" % "neo4j" % "1.9.M05" excludeAll(
        ExclusionRule(organization = "org.neo4j", name="neo4j-kernel")
      ),
    "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % "1.9.M05" % "test" classifier "tests" classifier "",
    "asm" % "asm-all" % "3.1",
    "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j-rest" % "2.1.0.RELEASE" excludeAll(
      ExclusionRule(organization = "org.neo4j")
      ),
     "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-rest-graphdb" % "1.9.M04",
     "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0-SNAPSHOT" withSources(),
     "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.13.1-SNAPSHOT" % "test" withSources(),
     "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.0" %"test",
     "securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT" withSources()
  )
```

What could I do to reduce this huge slug size? Even if I remove some documentations and jars sources, size would be huge.

It really seems that play app's target folder is sent .. despite of `.gitignore` file

Of course, I've created my Heroku app using this buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala

Besides, is there a way to precise in SBT (or play configuration), that certains dependencies like Specs2 (testing) should not be downloaded in Heroku production environment?

**EDIT ---------**

I've run the following command to show the actual size of what I pushed on Heroku:

```
MikaPc:wwa Mika$ heroku run bash    
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.9266        
~ $ du -h --apparent-size --max-depth 2       
5.3K    ./test/resources         
12K ./test/unit         
5.6K    ./test/functional          
6.5K    ./test/context          
8.5K    ./test/acceptance         
5.2K    ./test/integration         
47K ./test           
5.0K    ./app/helpers          
33K ./app/controllers           
11K ./app/models          
161K    ./app/assets          
34K ./app/views           
8.0K    ./app/applicationservices           
5.0K    ./app/repositories           
20K ./app/utils           
281K    ./app             
8.7M    ./target/scala-2.10           
1.4M    ./target/resolution-cache          
143K    ./target/streams             
60M ./target/staged           
71M ./target          
1.1M    ./.sbt_home/bin          
834K    ./.sbt_home/.sbt           
1.9M    ./.sbt_home         
30K ./public/images            
171K    ./public/javascripts          
9.6K    ./public/stylesheets         
214K    ./public         
4.0K    ./.ivy2/cache        
8.0K    ./.ivy2         
1.1M    ./.jdk/bin         
19M ./.jdk/lib         
203K    ./.jdk/include          
227M    ./.jdk/jre           
247M    ./.jdk             
2.8M    ./project/target          
20K ./project/project            
53M ./project/boot           
56M ./project         
12K ./conf           
375M    .
```

375 Mo before compression I imagine ending up to 222Mo .. hum

And the winner is: `227M    ./.jdk/jre`     taking part of the slug size. Is it...normal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku has recently changed the way that the JDK we deploy with your app is built. It's now a lot larger than previously. We have also upped the slug size limit so this is not going to impede your app other than making releases a little slower.

We'll get the docs updated to match the actual current limits.

Comment: @adib What ended up happening was that we found a way to reduce the size of the packaged JDK. You should be seeing dramatically reduced slug sized when pushing new releases. If not, please contact Heroku support.

Comment: @friism The Play Framework 2.1 "todolist" tutorial ends up with a 119.9MB slug size (just completed the tutorial and pushed a few seconds ago). Hope that you'll significantly increase the upper limit of slugs soon.

Comment: @friism Indeed! I've just pushed a new release of my own app and here are the numbers: Repo size: 186 MB and Slug size: 148 MB of 200 MB. Awesome diminution and far from the limit! Great :)

Comment: @adib with the updated smaller JDKs, are you still worried that you'll hit the 200 MB limit?

Comment: @friism Yes, because an "empty" app (the Play todolist example) already took more than half of the available space. I'd imagine a real app will need significantly more space.